# EF Core Sort a list by related data

Tags: list, sorting, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, many-to-many

I implemented objects like below in ASP.NET Core 3.1:

```
public class Content: BaseModel
    {
        public int ContentId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ContentCBlock> ContentCBlocks { get; set; } = new List<ContentCBlock>();
    }

public class CBlock : BaseModel
    {
        public int CBlockId { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ContentCBlock> ContentCBlocks { get; set; } = new List<ContentCBlock>();
    }

public class ContentCBlock
    {
        [Key]
        public int ContentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Content Content { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int CBlockId { get; set; }
        public virtual CBlock CBlock { get; set; }

        public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    }
```

and **DBContext**

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentCBlock>().HasKey(t => new { t.ContentId, t.CBlockId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentCBlock>()
                .HasOne(c => c.CBlock)
                .WithMany(c => c.ContentCBlocks)
                .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.CBlockId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<ContentCBlock>()
                .HasOne(c => c.Content)
                .WithMany(c => c.ContentCBlocks)
                .HasForeignKey(cc => cc.ContentId);
```

**DBSets:**

```
        public DbSet<ContentCBlock> ContentCBlocks { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }
        public DbSet<CBlock> CBlocks { get; set; }
```

Everything works fine, relations, lazyLoading, ... everything.
The question is How I can sort a **List of Contents** by **ContentCBlock.DisplayOrder**

*P.S.: I cannot change classes*

Comment: Can you show me your Dbcontext?

Comment: @BinaraThambugala I did

Comment: I can't see your DB sets?

Comment: @BinaraThambugala I added them too, what's the deal with dbsets?

Comment: didn't you try this. ```_context.Contents.OrderByDescending(c => c.DisplayOrder);``` or  ```_context.Contents.OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder);```

Comment: @BinaraThambugala Contents doesn't have the DisplayOrder, there were no question if the sorting property belongs to Content!!!  I have to sort a list of content by ContentCBlock.DisplayOrder ... Imaging fetching Contents of CBlock1 and order it as mentioned in its ContentCBlock!

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

```
_context.Contents.OrderBy(c => c.ContentCBlocks.
             OrderBy(c => c.DisplayOrder).Select(c => c.DisplayOrder).FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: It sorts in a weird order!  2,4,3,9,6